# ./ vs directory name in paths and file linking

Tags: javascript, php, html, directory

What is the difference between using ./ and directly writing a directory or file name when working with paths.

Suppose I have the following simple structure:

```
project
│   index.html  
│
└───pages
│   │   file1.html
│   │   file2.html
│   │
│   └───about
│       │   file3.html
│       │   file4.html
```

If I am say in `file1.html` what is the difference between writing the link is the following ways?

```html
<a href="./about/file3.html">Link</a>
```

vs.

```html
<a href="about/file3.html">Link</a>
```

**Important**

I know what `./` means!
I just want to know if there is a practical difference & advantage/disadvantage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the web, as far as I know, the two are functionally equivalent.

However, *inside a Node.js application*, the `./` differentiates local files from library files (ie. files coming from NPM/`node_modules`).

In other words:

```
import Foo from 'foo';
```

imports the `Foo` variable from the library called "foo", in `node_modules`, while:

```
import Foo from './foo'
```

would instead import `Foo` from a file called `foo.js` in the same directory.